# Error when trying npm install tslint and rxjs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ubuntu

I've tried `npm install tslint` and `npm install rxjs`, both run after `npm cache clean` and with `@latest` in the end. Every time I keep getting "UNMET PEER DEPENDECY rxjs@5.0.3" and "UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY tslint@4.3.1".

The entire failure stack is

> [jannik@jannik-dimsen app (AngularApp *)]$ npm install
>   first-app@0.0.0 /home/jannik/angular2apps/first-app
>
> ├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY rxjs@5.0.3
>
> └── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY tslint@4.3.1
>
> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
>
> npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.17: wanted {"os":"darwin","
>   arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
>
> npm WARN @angular/core@2.2.3 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12 but none was installed.
>   npm WARN @angular/http@2.2.3 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12 but none was installed.
>   npm WARN @angular/router@3.2.3 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12 but none was installed.
>   npm WARN codelyzer@2.0.0-beta.3 requires a peer of tslint@~4.0.0 but none was installed.
>   npm WARN tslint-loader@2.1.5 requires a peer of tslint@^3.0.0 but none was installed.
>
> npm ERR! code 1

Some sites suggested running `npm cache clean` but that didn't fix my problem, and I can't figure out why I can't install those npm modules. I've added them to the package.json file as well and tried a `npm install` giving the same error

Comment: did you find a solution to your issue, I have the same with ionic 2 project.

Comment: @french_dev I haven't found a solution yet, still trying to find one